# Expectimax Pruning

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, search-trees, minimax, pruning

I found the following question in my book:

> For probabilistic games like backgammon, where there is a resource
> limit, the RB-Expectimax algorithm is used.
>
> Assume that it is known that the heuristic function h in the
> Expectimax-RB algorithm holds: -1 <= h(s) <= 1 for each state s.
>
> How can this algorithm be pruned? Describe in detail the conditions of
> exaggeration, and explain the idea behind it.

I know that it can be pruned once we get exactly 1 or -1, but I don't think that's the answer and there might be a trick or something, am I right, what else might help?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to credit the book where you found that.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing